# How to iterate through multiple strings in Ksh

Tags: shell, loops, unix, copy, ksh

I'm looking to iterate through multiple strings using one for loop to perform a series of file copy operations in a Unix script.

So given a number of strings that denote directories:

```
file1="${HOME_PATH}/data1.dat"
file2="${HOME_PATH}/one/model1/data2.dat"
file3="${HOME_PATH}/two/model2/data3.dat"
file4="${HOME_PATH}/three/model3/data4.dat"
file5="${HOME_PATH}/three/model4/data5.dat"
file6="${HOME_PATH}/three/model5/data5.dat"
```

I want to copy each one of these to a particular directory:

```
dest1="${DEST_PATH}/data1.dat"
dest2="${DEST_PATH}/one/model1/data2.dat"
dest3="${DEST_PATH}/two/model2/data3.dat"
dest4="${DEST_PATH}/three/model3/data4.dat"
dest5="${DEST_PATH}/three/model4/data5.dat"
dest6="${DEST_PATH}/three/model5/data5.dat"
```

Is there a way to list each file location like I have done above and then simply for a for loop along the lines of...

```
for each i in {1..6}
do
   cp file[i] dest[i]
done
```

Comment: what about `find` and using `mkdir -p ${filename%*/}` and `cp` in a loop? then there is no need to specify the suffix in your subpath and you dont need to iterate over them.

Comment: Apologies guys, since looking into this further I have to implement this for KSH, not BASH (mu understanding is the syntax will be different) 

I have used the following:

`set -A fnames "<the six file paths"
set -A dnames "<the six destination paths>"

var=0   
    for f in ${fnames[@]}
    do 
      echo "I am copying $f to ${dnames[var]}";
      var=$((var+1))  
   done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indirection for this:

```
for i in {1..6}
do
  file="file$i"
  dest="dest$i"
  echo "${!file} ${!dest}" #or whatever you want to do with each file
done
```

From [How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)

> BASH allows you to expand a parameter indirectly -- that is, one
>   variable may contain the name of another variable:
>
> ```
>  # Bash
>  realvariable=contents
>  ref=realvariable
>  echo "${!ref}"   # prints the contents of the real variable
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
file[1]="${HOME_PATH}/data1.dat"
file[2]="${HOME_PATH}/one/model1/data2.dat"
file[3]="${HOME_PATH}/two/model2/data3.dat"
file[4]="${HOME_PATH}/three/model3/data4.dat"
file[5]="${HOME_PATH}/three/model4/data5.dat"
file[6]="${HOME_PATH}/three/model5/data5.dat" 

dest[1]="${DEST_PATH}/data1.dat"
dest[2]="${DEST_PATH}/one/model1/data2.dat"
dest[3]="${DEST_PATH}/two/model2/data3.dat"
dest[4]="${DEST_PATH}/three/model3/data4.dat"
dest[5]="${DEST_PATH}/three/model4/data5.dat"
dest[6]="${DEST_PATH}/three/model5/data5.dat"

for i in "${file[@]}"
do
    cp ${file[i]} ${dest[i]}
done
```